# Check if DIV has toggle activated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I having problems when applying the `toggle` to my `divs`. These divs are created after an `ajax` call which fetches data and creates the divs. After this, I'm applying the toggle for these divs by calling `activateToggles()`. So far, everything works fine. 
However, if I click '`load more`' which will fetch the next 10 rows, the ajax will append more divs on the page, the new divs will have the correct behavior but the previous ones will **toggle twice**, meaning they will expand and contract. 
If I load more, then the initial ones will **toggle x3**, next ones x2, and new ones would be ok.

I believe the problem is when the `activateToggles()` it shouldn't assign a `toggle` to the divs that already have it. But how do I check this?

```
  function activateToggles() {

        jQuery(function () {
            jQuery(".medical-details").hide();
            jQuery(".toggle").click(function () {

                var that = jQuery(this);

                    that.next().toggle("fast", function () {       
                    });
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Post a [mcve] please

Comment: Use delegated event handlers instead.

Comment: This is an example of an X/Y problem. You do not need to test that toggle is activated on each div, you need to delegate the event handler to a static parent container.

Comment: @mplungjan could you please give me an example? Do you mean like this: .jQuery(".toggle").on('click', 'a.myclass', function() ?

Comment: Yes. Like this `$("#divContainer").on("click",".toggle",function () {` - if you do not have a container `$(document).on("click",".toggle",function () {` will do it too and this is shorter: `$(this).next().toggle("fast", function () {       
                    });` if you do not need "that"